# HDFS replication factor on single node cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication

Can I have more than one replica's for single node cluster? i have updated replication factor as 2 in hdfs-site.xml and restarted all nodes, but still only one block created for new files, help me to get clarity on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't have more than one replication factor for a single node cluster. What makes you think that it is even possible?

Replication is the procedure to save your data so that you don't lose it in any worst conditions. If you're setting it to 2, that means you want your data to be copied on 2 nodes(machines) so that if one goes down you'll still have your data safe on another node.

Now, the default replication provided by Hadoop is 3. Which means there will 3 Replications(Copy) of data on 3 different nodes on different racks(That's another concept which is called Hadoop's Rack awareness)

So you won't be able to get more than one copy of your data on a Single node cluster. I hope it clears your query!

Comment: Thanks for detailed info..In a same node if we have two HDD partition, still is it possible to have 2 replica's?

Comment: No. It doesn't matter how many partitions you have in a single node. What matters is how many nodes you have. Like I have one hard disk drive on which I have windows installed. Now, I use VMWare and create 3 nodes of 20 GB each, so these will be counted as 3 different nodes.